# Linearization: Selecting of state variables to make the Jacobian matrix square

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, jacobian, linearization

I have 5 equations like:

[image]

My state variables are:

[image]

I cannot make Jacobi matrix square according the this state vector. What do you suggest for this operation? Should i change state vector, or can i produce 7 equations by using this vector?

Thanks,

[image]
NOTE: Arastas' approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dot{w}_z$ and $\dot{w}_x$ are not state variables since you do not have equations with their derivatives, namely $\ddot{w}_z$ and $\ddot{w}_x$. Remove them, and you have five equations for five states.

#### UPD

Define $x = [u,\ v,\ w_z,\ w_x,\ \theta]^\top$. Then the system can be written as (check it, typos are possible)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 5 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -10 & 4 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 14 & 10 & -1 \\ 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\\ \dot{x}_3\\ \dot{x}_4\\ \dot{x}_5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_3^2 + x_3x_4 + 2x_3x_2 \\ -5x_1x_3 \\ 10x_1x_3 \\ x_1x_3 + x_5\\ x_4\end{bmatrix}
$$
that is
$$
T \dot{x} = \psi(x).
$$
The matrix $T$ is invertible, and thus your model is
$$
\dot{x} = T^{-1}\psi(x) = f(x).
$$
Then you can compute the Jacobian.

Comment: Hi Arastas, if i make this, second equation will include x2_dot, x3_dot and x4_dot. I don't know how to use this kind of equation for linearization. I will add your approach as picture, it will be more clear.

Comment: Now, i have 5 equations. To calculate Jacobi, we should have only one equation like x4_dot=..., but in here we can see x4_dot in 3 equations. And we can say similar things about x2_dot and x3_dot. How can i calculate Jacobi?

Comment: I don't know where my mistake is :)))

Comment: Arastas this is AMAZING! Thanks a lot, this is a great solution for me. :)))